# Plot area between two quantiles in Altair

Tags: python, altair

I am trying to plot the data the between quantiles and so far I have only managed to create a plot with the area being to 0.

Here's my attempt so far which has the 25th and 75th percentiles, but unfortunately shades the entire region to the X axis, whereas I would like the shading to go between them.

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.cars()

base = alt.Chart(source).encode(alt.X("Year:T", title="Year"))

base.transform_quantile(
    "Miles_per_Gallon", probs=[0.25, 0.75], groupby=["Year"]
).mark_area(opacity=0.2).encode(alt.Y("value:Q", stack=None), alt.Color("prob:N"))
```

[image]

I was trying to use `alt.Y` and `alt.Y2` in the encoding for the area, but I could not find how to specify the desired probabilities.  Note that I need this solution to work for any quantile (not just special ones like the 25th, 50th and 75th percentiles).

Comment: I can't imagine what output to expect. Do you want to display only the difference in the classification values?

Comment: The end goal is to plot a line showing the median, and the bands that show `[50-x, 50+x]` percentiles.  By having each band be of low opacity, it ends up producing a plot showing the evolution of the spread of values over time while also showing the median and interquartile range.

Comment: You might be able to us `transform_pivot` to create to separate columns that you can use for Y and Y2.

Comment: @joelostblom Can you show how this works?  One difficulty I've been having with using Altair is that I struggle to see what the underlying data looks like after it transforms it, so my attempts at using `transform_pivot` have been unsuccessful.

Comment: I don't know on the top of my head, but I will try to look into it in the next few days if I can find the time. I share your sentiment about the struggles of not being able to view the data once transformed. Would an option for you be to use the pandas transform before passing the data to Altair instead?

Comment: I used to use Bokeh where I did process the data before using pandas, so I know how to do it that way, but I feel like Altair *should* be able to do what I'm asking, I just haven't found out how.  So ideally a solution featuring Altair would be preferred.